# Numpy: difference b/w A[:i][:j] and A[:i,:j]

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Why is there a difference in the following operations, How are they implemented in the library?

```
print(prov_img[:19][:20].shape)
Output : (19, 1250)

print(prov_img[:19,:20].shape)
Output : (19, 20)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`prov_img` is a 2d array here.

This code snippet is providing you the first 19 rows (0th row to 18th row) and 20 columns (0th column to 19th column) of `prov_img`:

```
>>> prov_img[:19,:20].shape
(19, 20)
```

---

Here, `prov_img[:19]` gives you the first 19 rows of `prov_img` and then adding `[:20]` means you are again taking the first 20 rows from the matrix you got from `prov_img[:19]`:

```
>>> prov_img[:19][:20].shape
(19, 1250)
```

Since there are 19 rows in `prov_img[:19]`, slicing the first 20 rows from it eventually providing you all the 19 rows. There is no slicing in columns and as a result you are getting output as `(19, 1250)` where 1250 is the number of columns in your `prov_img` matrix (2d array).

Answer (score 3):

`prov_img` is a 2d array

```
prov_img[:19, :]  # (19, 1250) - 19 rows of prov_img
(prov_img[:19, :])[:20, :]  # (19, 1250); a slice of rows, again
```

The `20` is ok, it just takes the whole thing, effectively

```
prov_img[:19, :][:,:]
```

Each `[]` is evaluated independently.

```
prov_img[:19, :20]
```

this selects 19 rows, and from those 20 columns.

```
prov_img[:19, :][:, :20]
```

is the same thing.

When applying indexing sequentially, you have to have a clear idea of what is happening at each stage.  Test them in stages.

In general if the you can index all dimensions at once, do so.  It's always better than the equivalent sequential version.

Answer (score 1):

For better understanding I will add one more example to yours:

**Code:**

```
x = np.zeros((20,20))

print(x[:3].shape)
print(x[:3][:3].shape)
print(x[:3, :3].shape)
```

**Gives:**

```
(3, 20)
(3, 20)
(3, 3)
```

**So...**

You get the same results from these two:

```
print(x[:3].shape)
print(x[:3][:3].shape)
```

because `x[:3]`, give the first three columns, and `x[:3][:3]` give the first three columns of the first three columns.